# Nginx and Phusion Passenger running but passenger-status showing 0 processes running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx, passenger

I have a rails app on a production server with Passenger and Nginx (with the Passenger module) installed. However, when I go to run `rvmsudo passenger-status`, it show that 0 processes are running.

For reference, here is my nginx.conf:

```
#user www-data;
user root;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

The `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` directory contains the relevant Server information.

Here is the output of `ps aux | grep nginx`:

```
root     11417  0.0  0.0  42412  1076 ?        Ss   13:13   0:00 nginx: master process /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
nobody   11418  0.0  0.0  42852  1844 ?        S    13:13   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

When I go to the site via my web browser, I get a "Welcome to nginx!" landing page.

I'm a total newbie at this stuff so there might be something dumb simple going on but I just need to get this started up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Output of `rvmsudo passenger-status`:

```
Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

export rvmsudo_secure_path=1

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

export rvmsudo_secure_path=0

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.
Version : 4.0.42
Date    : 2014-12-22 14:04:17 -0500
Instance: 11417
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
```

Output of `rvmsudo passenger-memory-stats`:

```
Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

export rvmsudo_secure_path=1

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

export rvmsudo_secure_path=0

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.
Version: 4.0.42
Date   : 2014-12-22 14:07:57 -0500
------------- Apache processes -------------
*** WARNING: The Apache executable cannot be found.
Please set the APXS2 environment variable to your 'apxs2' executable's filename, or set the HTTPD environment variable to your 'httpd' or 'apache2' executable's filename.


---------- Nginx processes ----------
PID    PPID   VMSize   Private  Name
-------------------------------------
11417  1      41.4 MB  0.1 MB   nginx: master process /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
11418  11417  41.8 MB  0.6 MB   nginx: worker process
### Processes: 2
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.71 MB


----- Passenger processes -----
PID    VMSize    Private  Name
-------------------------------
11399  218.3 MB  0.3 MB   PassengerWatchdog
11402  491.5 MB  0.4 MB   PassengerHelperAgent
11408  232.9 MB  1.1 MB   PassengerLoggingAgent
### Processes: 3
### Total private dirty RSS: 1.74 MB
```

Comment: so, do you have a Rails app deployed on this server?  If so, what does the vhost file look like?

Comment: The issue is that the app is on the server but it doesn't appear to be deploying. Any idea where I might find that vhost file? I'm not the one who initially configured things; this whole system was inherited.

Comment: according to the nginx.conf file, it should be under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.  Also, have you tried restarting nginx or passenger?

Comment: @tagCincy See answer below.

Comment: @tagCincy Also, I have restarted nginx a few times with no success.

Comment: can you post the actually output of `rvmsudo passenger-status` and `rvmsudo passenger-memory-stats`.  Simply explanation which suggest that the passenger process is not running, but I don't want to just to conclusions without all the info.

Comment: @tagCincy See edit above.

Comment: @tagCincy Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Phusion Passenger author here. I'm 99% sure this is just an Nginx configuration error.

First of all, Phusion Passenger [starts your app at the first request](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_why_does_the_first_request_take_a_long_time), so it's normal that you see '0 processes' -- unless explicitly configured otherwise with [passenger_pre_start](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerPreStart).

The clue is the fact that you see "Welcome to nginx" when you try to visit your site. In 99% of the cases, this means that you configured your virtual host wrong. Since you redacted your config file, I cannot tell you what exactly is wrong, but it indicates that Nginx is not associating your request with the virtual host block that you intended it to associate with. If you post your unredacted config file and the URL you're accessing with, I can tell you more. But otherwise, I can only tell you to study how Nginx's server name matching works.

Comment: Any chance I could send you the config file offline somehow?

Answer (score 0):

@tagCincy: There is one file under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and it looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name  REDACTED;

    ssl  on;
    ssl_certificate  REDACTED;
    ssl_certificate_key  REDACTED;

    #auth_basic "REDACTED";
    #auth_basic_user_file  REDACTED;

    client_max_body_size  250m;
    client_body_buffer_size  128k;

    access_log  REDACTED;
    error_log  REDACTED;

    root  REDACTED;

    passenger_enabled  on;
    rack_env  production;

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header ETag "";
        expires 1y;

        break;
    }

    # disable site via capistrano (cap deploy:web:disable)
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
        rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
}

server {
    listen  80;

    server_name  REDACTED;

    client_max_body_size  250m;
    client_body_buffer_size  128k;

    access_log  REDACTED;
    error_log  REDACTED;

    rewrite  ^ https://www.REDACTED.com$request_uri? break;
}
```